# Java: increasing speed of parsing large file

Tags: java, performance, csv, java-8, bigdata

I have csv file:
Lets call it **product.csv**

```
Product_group | Product producer | Product_name | CODE | RANDOM_F_1 | ... | RANDOM_F_25
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Electronic    |   Samsung        |  MacBook_1   |  60  |   0.8      | ... | 1.2
Electronic    |   Samsung        |  MacBook_2   |      |   0.8      | ... | 1.2
...           |   ...            |  ...         |      |   ...      | ... | ...
Electronic    |   Samsung        | MacBook_9999 |   63 |   1.2      | ... | 3.1
Electronic    |   Samsung        | MacBook_9999 |   64 |   1.2      | ... | 3.1
```

I will try to explain this csv file:
The couple **Product_name** + **CODE** are unique (if code present), RANDOM_F_1 are fields with random values.

So, my goal:

I have java class, which generate this csv file. And when it generates new file - it will clean **product.csv**, and generate new one with *other random attributes*.

Now, i have a goal - not overwrite this random fields in new csv generation.

So, i have one idea - create copy of this csv file before cleaning, and if *MacBook_9999* present in copy file - just use this raw in new generation of file.

My code now looks like:

```
public void createProducts(List<Products> products) {
//copying file
   for(Product newProduct : products) {
      Product previousProduct = findPreviousProduct(newProduct);
      if(previousProduct != null) {
         newProduct  = previousProduct;
      }
      addToCsv(newProduct );
   }
}

private void copyFile() {
 //here i am copying file by FileInputStream and FileOutputStream
}

private Product findPreviousProduct(Product product) {
File copyFile = new File(...);
//creation BufferReader br here, in try with resources
previousProduct = br.lines().parallel()
   .map(Product::new)
   .filter(e -> e.getName.equals(product.getName) && //here is comparison by code)
   .findFirst().orElse(...);
//return statement here
}
```

Everythink works fine, but i faced one performance problem after this check adding, see below test example (file with 12k raws):

**BEFORE**: 3seconds

**AFTER**:  2minutes 20seconds

So, the question is: **how can i boost it ?** Should i use other way to save my *RANDOM* fields?

Because it is really low perfomance. If i will have 100k raws it will take 22minutes :(

Idea with saving data in hash map (Blaž Mrak comment), and getting row by key is brittiant, but if i will have 500-700k of objects - my Heap memory will ends.

Than you, developers

Comment: What's preventing you from using a proper database?

Comment: Yep, i can not use database in this case.

Comment: You're re-copying and re-reading the old file for every single product.  Why?  A better approach, which will scale to at least a few thousand products, is to read the old file once, create an in-memory representation (probably a map to facilitate lookups), and consult it when creating the new file.

Comment: I am re-copying only 1 time, and re-reading it for every element in List<Product> products. The question about in-memory representation. What about StackOverFlowError? In case when i will have million of elements ?

Comment: Such data usage seems to call for an embedded file based database like H2. It depends on the data processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have O(n) complexity, but a O(n^2), which means that for 100k lines your code will run for 220 minutes, not 22. What makes it worse is that you are reading the file each time you call findPreviousProduct. I would suggest first loading csv into memory and then searching it:

```
//somewhere else... MyCsvReader or sth
public List<Product> readPerviousProducts() {
   File copyFile = new File(...);
   ...

   return br.lines().parallel()
       .map(Product::new).toList();
}

//then in your class
public void createProducts(List<Product> products, List<Product> previousProducts) {
   for(Product newProduct : products) {
      Product previousProduct = findPreviousProduct(previousProducts, newProduct);
      if(previousProduct != null) {
         newProduct  = previousProduct;
      }
      addToCsv(newProduct );
   }
}

private Product findPreviousProduct(List<Product> previousProducts, Product product) {
   return previousProducts.filter(e -> e.getName.equals(product.getName) && //here is comparison by code)
   .findFirst().orElse(...);
}
```

Give this a try first to see if there are some performance improvements. The second optimization is to create a HashMap instead of a List. You create a key() method on the product, which will return a unique string generated from name and code. (basically just **name** + _ + **code**)

```
//somewhere else
public List<Product> readPerviousProducts() {
   File copyFile = new File(...);
   ...

   return br.lines().parallel()
       .map(Product::new)
       .toMap((product) -> product.key(), (product) -> product);
}

public void createProducts(List<Product> products, HashMap<String, Product> previousProducts) {
   for(Product newProduct : products) {
      Product previousProduct = findPreviousProduct(previousProducts, newProduct);
      if(previousProduct != null) {
         newProduct  = previousProduct;
      }
      addToCsv(newProduct );
   }
}

private Product findPreviousProduct(List<Product> previousProducts, Product product) {
   return previousProducts.get(product.key());
}
```

You can then compare how much faster each solution is :)

Comment: Well, it is good idea. But if i will have 500k+ objects in the map, i will get StackOverFlow/Heap or OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Are you sure about that and are you sure that you couldn't increase the memory allowance?

Comment: Yes, i can not increase my stack memory limit.

Comment: Then you will need to use something like H2. Fill the database and then query it. Basically just modify the readPreviousProducts() to 1. clean the db 2. insert into db and findPreviousProduct() to query the db.